# Cut comma separated results and echo just 5 at max via php

Tags: php, wordpress, string

I'm using wordpress and own a custom field which is a list of names, separated by comma and listed in order of importance. Sometimes they are just too many, so I wanna set my wordpress php to just show the first 5 results.

I'm trying this, but it isn't working. Can you kindly correct it?

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'players_name_list', true) if (++$i == 5) break; ?>
```

Comment: What about `foreach ($aPlayer in array_slice(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'players_name_list', true).explode(","), 0, 5, true)) {echo $aPlayer}`

Comment: Used as it's typed it doesn't seem to work, can you explain me better? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code and check if it's working

```
$players = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'players_name_list', true);
$i = 1;
foreach($players as $player){
   if($i < 6){
    echo $player;
   }
$i++;
}
```

Comment: It's not working. Showing no result, all blank. Maybe you forgot to tell system that names are comma separated?